# supervisor with gunicorn and no logging

Tags: gunicorn, supervisord

I am trying to run a small WSGI application with gunicorn + supervisor and although everything works correctly, I am unable to get logging to go to a file.

If I run the gunicorn command directly, it does work however, sending all the output to the file I am specifying, but as soon as I try the same thing with supervisor it doesn't.

I recently moved this small WSGI app from uwsgi to gunicorn, and I had no issues with uwsgi logging to a file, so I suspect I am either missing something that gunicorn needs when working with supervisor or there is a problem that is non-obvious to me.

The app is called `upload` and this is how the supervisor config for that app looks like:

```
[program:upload]
command=/vagrant/venv/bin/gunicorn -w 4 upload.wsgi:application --log-file /vagrant/log/application.log --log-level debug
directory=/vagrant
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

The file `/vagrant/log/application.log` never gets any input. If I run the above `command` directly it does, with the normal gunicorn info about booting up workers:

```
2013-08-20 14:01:24 [1898] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 17.5
2013-08-20 14:01:24 [1898] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
2013-08-20 14:01:24 [1898] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (1898)
2013-08-20 14:01:25 [1898] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-08-20 14:01:25 [1903] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1903
...
```

I've also attempted to use `redirect_stderr` in the supervisor config but that also did make the log file to get any info.

Is this a known problem? Or do I need some other flag? (Note the app is using `gevent`, not sure if that is relevant to this problem)

Comment: Could be a permissions issue, supervisor spawning gunicorn with a different user than the log file.